# CoinBase Callback URL in Java

Tags: transactions, api, coinbase.com

I using CoinBase API for transactions in a game. I assign a callback URL with the address so as to get instant notification on payment transactions. the URL is called but it is not sending any data. Actually which parameter to get is not clear so used getParameterMap method, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get this working. I used getReader() method to get the required details.

Comment: Next issue I have is that it gives me transaction address and amount only. Can I get the transaction Id as well?